# Why is my php code not printing a submitted form?

Tags: php, html

I'm making my first intranet website for my school project, but as soon as i try to include a simple line of php in my html, the php code doesn't work

I don't know whats wrong with a small line of code that refuses to work. I need help

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Virtual Faculty </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>

                    <h1><img class="logo" src="img/casa.jpg" align="middle">VIRTUAL FACULTY</h1>

            </div>

                <nav>
                    <div class="box1" align="middle">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ABM11.html">ABM 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ABM12.html">ABM 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="GAS.html">GAS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="HUMMS.html">HUMMS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="STEM11.html">STEM 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="STEM12.html">STEM 12</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <div class="box2">
                    <h2>You are in:</h2>
                    <h3>ABM 12 Classroom</h3>
                        <img class="img-eye" src="img/das.jpg" alt="Me, the one and only">

<form action="ABM12.html" method="get">
    Name: <input type="text" name="Student">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<br>

<?php echo $_GET["Student"] ?>

                </div>
            <a href="#here"> Go down to the link </a>
                <a id="here" href="contact.html">Visit my contact page here</a>


        </body>
    </html>    

i just want to print out the Student's name submitted below
```

Comment: "i dont know whats wrong with a small line of code that refuses to work, i need help " Can be a "million" things wrong with it like 1) PHP not working on the webserver 2) The file is not a `.php` file.. i advice you to read the [Getting Started](http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php) part off the good PHP manual,

Answer (score 0):

When your passing value through form it is better to use Post method

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="//Pass your file name or any url you looking for" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and you can use it in that file or in recent file like

```
<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
```

Comment: "When your passing value through form it needs to be Post" html forms can also pass GET requests just fine no problem here..

Comment: usually Get i used for just retrieve values

Comment: "usually Get i used for just retrieve values" true you better off using POST i agree with that.. But saying the html form **needs** to be POST is plain wrong GET should also work just fine..